# Means by which Devotion , Knowledge and Detachment, can be integrated together in the Kaliyuga

Tags: krishna, kali-yuga

What is the means explained by Lord Shri Krishna, by which  Devotion, Knowledge and Detachment, can be integrated together in the Kaliyuga?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by asceticism or thrive together. Lord Krishna defines the three ways to attain to Him in chapter XV of Uddhava Gita. those are Karma, Bhakti, and Jnana. And by having the mind centered on Him alone, one attains the all.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda, Thanks.I shall edit my question appropriately...

Comment: asceticism is one of those words that has different connotations to different people, most of them negative. Sankara says that the Lord is gained through one thing - hankering. There is the story of the guru who held his disciple head under water for a long time. When he released him, the guru asked the disciple how he felt. He said he could only think of one thing - to get a breath of air. The guru replied that when he wanted the Lord the same way he wanted that breath of air, the Lord would be seen. Hankering is all that is required.

Comment: In Kaliyuga, nama sankeertana (chanting the lord's name) helps attain all three goals. There are certain rules to be practised while continuing the nama sankeertana yoga.

Answer (score 1):

srimad bhagavatam saptahika especially(10th and 11th books) is the means by which to integrate bhakti ,jnana and vairagya in kaliyuga infact this is what gives the three power and enthusiasm in this yuga.